# Find sites in file that are visited by the user using python

Tags: python

This `csv` contents `log` of sites

```
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:52 +0300] "GET http://www.livejournal.com/" 200 37306 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:52 +0300] "GET http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activeview?avi=BplxjLSweV_HMGOq27Qat0ab4CwAAAAAQATgByAEJwAIC4AIA4AQBoAYW&cid=5GjqG9rprW9xwh1phu29tPRuFcg&id=osdtos&ti=1&adk=860542529&p=60,30,310,330&tos=79582,17331,0,0,0&mtos=76067,93398,93398,93398,93398&rs=3&ht=0&tfs=2141&tls=188619&mc=1&lte=0.88&bas=0&bac=1&fp=correlator%3D3916897255826749%26eid%3D108809080%26iu%3D%252F267277916%252FInPostListing_HomePage_mobile%26oid%3D3%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.livejournal.com%252F&afp=%26output%3Djson_html%26impl%3Dfif%26dt%3D1461595180209%26adx%3D30%26ady%3D60%26ifi%3D2%26flash%3D0&r=u&bs=360,560&bos=360,560&ps=360,5085&ss=360,640&tt=67467&pt=121152&deb=1-1-1-113-95-30&tvt=122535&uc=94&tgt=nf&cl=0" 200 601 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:52 +0300] "GET http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activeview?avi=BObawLyweV7f-La-Atgf6p72oAQDr_4mR1gIAABABOAHIAQHgAgDIA5sE4AQBoAYawhMYChAQg5OS21siCAgCEAEYASAAGM296MkD&cid=5Gh0aQicSkg4zT2OREhjaepgd8g&id=osdtos&ti=1&adk=1560649554&p=60,30,120,264&tos=11676,0,0,0,0&mtos=6256,6256,6256,6256,6256&rs=3&ht=0&tfs=1366&tls=187932&mc=1&lte=1&bas=0&bac=1&fp=correlator%3D4427962225102195%26eid%3D108809080%26iu%3D%252F267277916%252FPB_Rubicon_mobile_HP%26oid%3D3%26ifk%3D3230326733%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.livejournal.com%252F&afp=%26output%3Djson_html%26impl%3Ds%26dt%3D1461595182915%26ifi%3D1%26flash%3D0&r=u&bs=360,560&bos=640,280&ps=640,4268&ss=360,640&tt=186403&pt=1529&deb=1-1-1-33-38-27&tvt=11683&iframe_loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livejournal.com%2F&is=300,250&uc=37&tgt=nf&cl=0" 200 601 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300] "GET http://rtax.criteo.com/delivery/rta/rta.js?netId=4024&cookieName=crtg_rta&rnd=61599440177&varName=crtg_content" 200 2996 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300] "GET http://l-stat.livejournal.net/tmpl/??Widgets/commreader.tmpl?v=1360820296&tm=1623994;uselang=ru" 200 1256 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300] "GET http://xc3.services.livejournal.com/ljcounter/?d=srv:bil1-ws21,r:0,j:0,uri:%22%2F%22,vig:0,extra:" 200 317 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300] "GET http://autocontext.begun.ru/autocontext2_async.js" 302 597 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300] "GET http://montblanc.rambler.ru/mb" 200 1853 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300] "GET http://awaps.yandex.ru/0/9999/001001.gif?0-0-258-0-&timestamp=258&awcode=6&subsection=0" 200 456 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300] "GET http://www.tns-counter.ru/V13a***R%3E*sup_ru/ru/UTF-8/tmsec=lj_noncyr/312895297" 200 541 "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36" 9445
```

I got this log, when I visited only `http://www.livejournal.com/`
I want to determine what sites was visited by users. 
What can help with it? 
I think about `re`, but I think it doesn't exactly.

Comment: How should the output look like?

Comment: print  `urls` which were visited by user. For this data `http://www.livejournal.com/`

Comment: Why? Is that because it is on first line?

Comment: No, because I really visited this site. But others I didn't visited. It's file for example [file](https://yadi.sk/i/NnT7q2I_rf3Jn). I visited there only 3 `url`

Comment: Then the file is not very useful, it it?

Comment: you can click to button under the yellow button on the right `Скачать` and you download this file

Comment: I mean there is no information about you visiting the site.

Comment: no, there is 3 string with facebook.com, 4pda.ru and livejournal.com

Comment: But how could I possibly know that you've visited those sites?

Comment: I install tracker to my phone and I visited this 3 sites. After that I download my log and get this file. Brawser, when it connect with `url` visited some `url` too. So this file is too big

Comment: Sure, page gathers data from other sites (e.g. for adds) but that is not part of the question.

Comment: I want to ignore this `url` and after go on a loop get only `url`, that I visited. Maybe I shoul delete `url`, that include some words?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111761/discussion-between-pacholik-and-hellmoore).

Answer (score 0):

That log does not contain that information. You may possibly find it in your browser's history file.

Comment: 1, 83 and 93 strings

Comment: Sure, but where did you get those numbers? Not in the file.

Comment: Open file and you see this address in this strings

Comment: How if you wouldn't tell me what should I look for or at which lines?

Comment: So I find the way to determine this sites, so I ask this question!

Comment: You've found the way?

Comment: Unfortunately, not find

Comment: That's because there is none.

Comment: I delete all `url`, that have `CONNECT` and `POST` requests and `url`, that ends with `.js, .json, .png, .jpeg ` and others file. But it did't change situation a lot